# Find the average value of the function $f(x, y) = −x + 5$ on the triangular region with vertices $(0, 0), (0, 2)$, and $(2, 2)$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

From graphing, I was able to see that the regions top-bound is y=x, and the lower bound is y=0. Thus, for my integral this is what I got:
$$ \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{x} (-x+5)dydx $$
After integrating, i found the answer to be $ \frac{22}{3} $.

The area of the region is just a right triangle, therefore it is 2.
So for the average value: $$ f_{ave} = \frac{1}2 \times \frac{22}{3} = \frac{11}3$$

However, this is deemed wrong. Am I setting up my bounds correctly?

Comment: It must be $\int_0^2(\int_0^y(-x+5)dx)dy$

Comment: I thought, for $dy$, the upper bound is $y=2$ and the lower bound is $y=x$.

Comment: Or $\int_0^2(\int_x^2 (-x+5)dy)dx$

Comment: I'll give it a go with the 3rd equation given, however I am not seeing as to why it would be x to 2. Is it because essentially x cannot be greater than 2 by the line?

Comment: @GReyes So, I ended up getting $\frac{26}{3}$ and it is incorrect by Cengage standards. I don't really see any other way to create the bounds for integration other than how you and I set it up.

Comment: $f$ is between $-0+5=5$ (when $x=0$) and $-2+5=3$ (when $x=2$), so $26/3$ must be incorrect.

Comment: $26/3$ is correct but is not the average value. Divide it by $2$ (the area).

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh yeah, tired brain. Totally forgot to do that with this result. Which is $\frac{13}{3} $ and is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Not $11/3$ but $13/3.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeah, sorry again - that is what I had put as my answer, typo lol. Thanks.